# How to disable dependency resolution during 'package' in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

We have project with multiple subprojects and complex inter-dependencies. Subprojects share similar sets of external dependencies (Spring, Apache etc).

It take enormous amount of time for dependencies resolution (possibly because of redundant dependencies checks) even in offline mode.

How to solve this? How can we disable updating and re-resolving external dependencies during packaging.

version: 0.12.1

Comment: Which version of SBT are you using? As of 0.11, even projects with massive dependencies (I have them) handle the automatic update check efficiently. Only when you do it explicitly (force it) does it take a long time.

Comment: 0.12.1. it doesn't happens every time, but when it occurs - it's tooo long, because it checks same dependencies for every depend subproject

Comment: actually our problem is that we have dependency to internal project in  ivy/nexus - so every time it changes (it changes very often) we have new resolving. Same after branch change in Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`skip in update := true` will prevent `update` from doing any work.  It uses the results of the previous `update` instead.

Note that this means that `update` must have been run (possibly indirectly) since the last `clean`, changes to dependency configuration since the last run will be ignored, and the cache must still contain the jars from the previous `update`.

Running `update` directly will override the `skip` setting and cause `update` to run normally.

Finally, similar sets of dependencies doesn't necessarily mean dependency resolution will be any faster.  It only means that network access, downloading, and metadata parsing shouldn't be done more than once per dependency.

Comment: in which file do i have to metione ` skip in update := true `